# ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc'

Tags: python, scipy

When trying to load an image file with `scipy.misc.imread()`, I receive this unexpected error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghita/PycharmProjects/image_processing/venv/test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import imread,  imsave
ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc' (/home/ghita/PycharmProjects/image_processing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py)
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `imread` [has been removed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html) from `scipy.misc`. They now recommend that you use `imread` from [the imageio package](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/).